# get all form selected label

Tags: jquery

i need to jquery script for show or append all selected lable of chekbox , radio button , options from form to views in page .

like andvanced search form , after submit show your selected options in top of result list .

Comment: Sorry to say, but, I am not able to understand your question. :-(

Comment: i need too show under search form : your result based on : lable 1 , lable 2 , ...  and each your selected in search form whith jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

All your elements will need to be inside a form tag.

There is a demo at the bottom of that page that lists all the values of a form printed on screen. You can use that as a starting point.

Comment: yes i know serialozeArray demo , but it take values and not lable .